# Maven command line equivalent of Eclipse Alt-F5

Tags: eclipse, maven, command-line

Does anynody know if there is a maven command line equivalent (mvn .....) to the Eclipse Alt-F5 popup window. Assume default window check boxes for (Update dependencies, Update project config, Refresh workspace... and clean projects)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> ("Update Maven Project" command) is a specific Eclipse feature. Eclipse M2E reads Maven configurations (pom.xml) and process this Maven configurations into Eclipse project configurations, normally they will be turned into equivalent facets, build paths, etc. Sometimes it will need additional plugins. The command "Update Maven Project" will refresh all this settings, so there is no `mvn` equivalent commands with one exception below.

But you have a `mvn` equivalent for the option "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases": `mvn -U ...`

Reference: https://manpages.org/mvn

Answer (score 0):

No.

Maven does not know about Eclipse. You can use Maven to purge the local repository or to update Snapshots for a build, but the main part of Alt-F5 is to sync Eclipse with Maven.

Comment: I didnt hold out much hope that there was. The reason I asked the question, was that I want to create a super script (Eclipse Run Configuration) Launch Group. This will build Project 1, which is an Antlr4 parser, resulting in a Java JAR file, which Project 2 has on its class path. Project 2 is a Maven project, but when I looked at putting the Project 1 JAR as a dependency in the POM, this feature seems deprecated. When I rebuild Porject 1, I simply use Alt-F5 and Eclipse doesnt the job and rebuilds all the executables in Project 2. But I cant use that feature in the super script.

Comment: If Project 1 and Project 2 are both Maven projects, then you can simply declare a `<dependency>`. You can even use Workspace Resolution.